problem with tikz in placement of node's label
I can't get the arcs and rounded arrows to work properly in this figure in tikz, especially as the node options don't work.
Here's what I want to do

i try with this :
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    c/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=2cm, inner sep=2mm, align=center},
    f/.style={draw, thick, -latex},
]
    % Les cadres de texte
    \node[c] (a) {$3x+2=5x+8$};
    \node[c] (b) [yshift=-2cm] {$5x+8=3x+5$};
    \node[ellipse, draw, xshift=-2cm, yshift=-1cm, minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm] (c1) {$\times 2$};
    \node[ellipse, draw, xshift=2cm, yshift=-1cm, minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm] (d) {$\times 2$};

    % Les flèches courbes
    \draw[thick,anchor=east,-,bend left=45] (a) to node {} (d);
    \draw[f] (a) to[out=30, in=150] node[above] {} (c1);
    \draw[f, bend right=30] (c1) to node[midway, left] {} (b);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


\draw[f] (a) to[out=  0, in=90]  (d) to[out=270, in=  0] (b); \draw[f] (a) to[out=180, in=90] (c1) to[out=270, in=180] (b);?

thanks it works ````
f/.style={draw, thick, -},
g/.style={draw, thick,-latex}
]
% Les flèches courbes
\draw[f] (a) to[out=0, in=90]  (c1);
\draw[g] (c1) to[out=270, in=0] (b);
\draw[f] (a) to[out=180,in=90] (d) ;
\draw[g] (d) to[out=270,in=180] (b);```

In my opinion, you are sometimes using syntax that doesn't exist in this way.
My tip would be: use clear, simple and recognizable names. And leave out everything that has nothing to do with the problem.
But to fix this now:
Solution 1.
Use sth. like
\draw[thick] (a.west) to[bend right=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$\times 2$}  (b.west); 


\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
c/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=2cm, inner sep=2mm, align=center},
f/.style={draw, thick, -latex},
]
% Les cadres de texte
\node[c] (a) {$3x+2=5x+8$};
\node[c] (b) [yshift=-2cm] {$5x+8=3x+5$};

% New ======================
\draw[thick] (a.west) to[bend right=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$\times 2$}  (b.west); 
    
\draw[thick] (a.east) to[bend left=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$\times 2$}  (b.east); 
% =====================
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Solution 2.
To avoid this bend-syntax you could consider a rounded corners-solution:

\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
c/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=2cm, inner sep=2mm, align=center},
f/.style={draw, thick, -latex},
]
% Les cadres de texte
\node[c] (a) {$3x+2=5x+8$};
\node[c] (b) [yshift=-2cm] {$5x+8=3x+5$};

% New²  ======================
\draw[thick, rounded corners=4mm, ->] (a.east)   -- ([xshift=5mm]a.east)
  -- ([xshift=5mm]b.east)  node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$\times 2$}
     -- (b.east); 

\draw[thick, rounded corners=4mm, ->] (a.west)   -- ([xshift=-5mm]a.west)
  -- ([xshift=-5mm]b.west)  node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$\times 2$}
     -- (b.west); 
% =====================
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

